# BigInt misbehaving on large numbers

Tags: javascript

I have two cases where BigInt misbehaves completely.

For completeness I attach the documentation of `BigInt` [BigInt doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and I quote

> BigInt.asIntN()
>     Wraps a BigInt value to a signed integer between -2^(width-1) and 2^(width-1 - 1).
>
> BigInt.asUintN()
>   Wraps a BigInt value to an unsigned integer between 0 and 2^(width - 1).

For 64 bit positive integer the max is `9223372036854775808`
For 64 bit signed integer the min is `-9223372036854775808`

Case 1:

```
const max: BigInt = BigInt.asUintN(64, BigInt(9223372036854775806));
console.log("max is: " + max);
```

and prints

```
9223372036854775808 when it should print:
9223372036854775806
```

why? It works on small numbers like 10, 100 etc but fails on the limit.

Case 2:

```
const min: BigInt = BigInt.asIntN(64, BigInt(-9223372036854775808));
console.log("bits: " + min.toString(2).length);
```

and prints:

```
bits: 65
```

when clearly according to the documentation it should be `64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the number as string for conversion to `BigInt`.

```js
const max = BigInt.asUintN(64, BigInt('9223372036854775806'));
console.log("max is: " + max);
```

Comment: This indeed prints the correct value, but `min` is still 65 bits on the second case

Comment: or alternatively a bigint literal